# Sluggish Flash/HTML5 in Firefox 30.0

Tags: firefox, performance, flash-player, html5

There are websites that have video playing back in the backround and **removethebackground.com** is one of those sites. This kind of effect slows browser's response almost to a crawl unless I switch to another tab.

Here's video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kh3MVX-kdo4&feature=youtu.be

Why in Chrome, IE 11 and Opera it plays fine?

**UPDATE:** Okay this is weird. I have restarted Firefox in safe-mode with all addons disabled and video was playing smooth. This indicated to me that there was problem with addons and extensions and I disabled them all manually one-by-one after restarting in normal mode. But video was sluggish again despite all addons and extensions I disabled.

This is not clear to me. Are there other things that Firefox not shows me which can be disabled?

Comment: Do you have plugins or addin's installed in firefox?  If so, disable all and try again.  How much RAM and which windows?

Comment: Do you have flash player version 14.0.0.145? If not upgrade.

Comment: Hey guys. Check for new information added.